# Beamer columns won't align minted code and TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, minted

I'm trying to create a two column Beamer slide, with the first column displaying a short minted code listing, and the second column displaying a TikZ diagram.

Unfortunately the minted code listing is getting pushed to the bottom of the slide, despite the use of `[t]` placement specifiers both the `\begin{columns}` and `\columns` directives. Ideally I'd like the code aligned to the top of the diagram.

LaTeX code is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning,shapes,shadows,arrows}

\usemintedstyle{default}
\definecolor{mintedbg}{rgb}{0.8,0.8,0.8}
\newminted{cpp}{bgcolor=mintedbg}
\newminted{make}{bgcolor=mintedbg}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Pointers}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column[t]{0.25\paperwidth}
\begin{cppcode}
int a = 5;
int * ptr = &a; 
\end{cppcode}
\column[t]{0.7\paperwidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{r}=[rectangle, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, draw=black!100, fill=blue!20]
\tikzstyle{textr}=[rectangle, outer sep=0pt, inner sep=0pt, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=0.5cm, draw=black!100]
\matrix[draw=black!100, row sep=1pt, column sep=1pt]
{
\node[textr] {Address}; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[textr] {Data Value}; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[textr] {Notes}; \\
\node[r, name=addr1] {0xFFFFFFA0}; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data1] {5}; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {int a=5}; \\
\node[r, name=addr2] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data2] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
\node[r, name=addr3] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data3] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
\node[r, name=addr4] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data4] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
\node[r, name=addr5] {0xFFFFFFB0}; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data5] {0xFFFFFFA0}; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {int * ptr=a;}; \\
\node[r, name=addr6] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data6] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
\node[r, name=addr7] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data7] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
\node[r, name=addr8] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data8] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
\node[r, name=addr9] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node[r, name=data9] { }; \pgfmatrixnextcell \node {}; \\
};
\draw[line width=2pt, ->] (data5.north) .. controls (data3.north) and (addr3.south) .. (addr1.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi Simon, [Welcome to TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043)! I've removed the thanks. It's just the style here, and thanks is best expressed as upvotes for those answers you find helpful.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the baseline of your picture to the top of the picture:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
```

Normally a baseline of a tikz picture is set to the bottom, and it seems that minted sets its baseline to the top, resulting in the problem you experienced.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I can't upvote yet, so a text thanks will have to do :)